# Postgres: average user response time from interaction with a bot

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rails-postgresql, response-time

I have a table that stores all messages between users and a bot (basically a state machine), and I'm trying to find all pairs of message/response from this table, in order to calculate each user's average response time. The caveat is, that not all outgoing messages get a response.

Each row stores message_id, user_id, created_at (timestamp), state_code and outgoing (boolean).

I have been looking at window functions, with the intention of using lag and lead to find the relevant pairs of messages and then calculate the difference between their created_at values, which averaged over each user would give us each user's avg. response time. The problem with this is that I have no way of assuring that both messages were issued with the same sate_code. Ideas?

**UPDATE:** you can assure that a user's message is a response to a given outgoing message if they have the same state code. So, for example

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ message_id ║ user_id ║ created_at ║ state_code ║ outgoing ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║          1 ║      11 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         20 ║ t        ║
║          2 ║      11 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         20 ║ f        ║
║          3 ║      11 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         22 ║ t        ║
║          4 ║      11 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         21 ║ t        ║
║          5 ║      12 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         45 ║ t        ║
║          6 ║      12 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         46 ║ f        ║
║          7 ║      12 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         46 ║ t        ║
║          8 ║      12 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         20 ║ f        ║
║          9 ║      12 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         43 ║ t        ║
║         10 ║      13 ║ mm/dd/yy   ║         20 ║ t        ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

In this case the pairs are, messages 1 and 2, and messages 6 and 7.
Nevertheless, only messages 1 and 2 matter, since user 1 is responding from state 20 to one of our outgoing messages received while in state 20.

Comment: Care to give some example data or pseudo-code that shows the required business logic for which messages are and are not related?

Comment: Of course, I just added some dummy data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then each time the `outgoing` is false, you want the `created_at` from preceding row with the same `user_id` and `state_code`.

I'm not sure how you would use the windows functions for this.  Here is an approach using correlated subqueries:

Here is one way:

```
select t.*,
       (select created_at
        from t t2
        where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
              t2.state_code = t.state_code and
              t2.outgoing = 't' and
              t2.created_at < t.created_at
        order by t2.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_created_at
 from t
```

You can then do your date arithmetic to get what you want (mostly that `prev_created_at` is not `NULL`).

If you know that the previous row is the "one just before", you can do something similar with `lag()`:

```
 select t.*
 from (select t.*,
              lag(created_at) over (partition by user_id, state_code order by created_at) as prev_created_at,
              lag(outgoing) over (partition by user_id, state_code order by created_at) as prev_outgoing
       from t
      ) t
where t.outgoing = 'f' and t.prev_outgoing = 't';
```

Comment: Don't you want an ORDER BY in the OVER clauses?

Comment: +1 - The OP wasn't clear on all corner cases.  If there is an outgoing state 20 message, and an incoming state 20 message, but with other messages in between, all for the same user, do these still make a pair?  Either way, this should give the OP plenty to work with to fit that actual requirement :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but this has helped out a lot!

I ended up using a less convoluted solution by joining the table with itself on several conditions.... thanks again!